# Android placing buttons depending on the background

Tags: android, layout, background, resolution, device

Basicly I'm making an app in which you search for items. So I have a background, and there are items/stuff on it. You have to click on the items that are relevant to win. The problem is, I don't know how to make this support all devices. I'm currently using relativelayout. Do I have to make a different layout for every resolution or is there an easier way to deal with this problem? I currently place the buttons this way:

```
<Button
             android:id="@+id/xxx"
             style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
             android:layout_width="120dp"
             android:layout_height="40dp"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_marginBottom = "25dp"
             android:layout_marginRight = "85dp" />
```

On top of an item.

Even if I use the right resolution to program it, sometimes there is a slight deviation to the left/right/up/down. (I do disable the action bar, but in xml it is still displayed).

Extra information:

People don't seem to understand what my question is. I basicly have a background, let's say, of a forest. I want the user to click on the flower that's on my forest background. So I place a button on the location of the flower, make the button invisible. So if people click on the flower it will give a "correct" sign or something. But the problem is, if I make the button overlap on the flower so it works on my phone for example, the button won't be overlapping on the same location on a tablad, it will be slightly off.

Comment: Difficult to say with the limited information.  If you want a grid you could do a Vertical LinearLayout containing multiple Horizontal LinearLayouts containing a number of buttons.  You could even use ImageButtons and put the pictures of the 'items/stuff' directly on the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure if I completely understand what you up to, but You may try to decide proportions of your items regarding to screen size, so you can create function that will take dimensions of device's screen size using WindowManager class, and then let's say you want 1% of width and height so divide both dimensions and apply values to your item.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Recycle view. 
Try to watch this, i think it's helpful:
[RecyclerView + CardView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nw9JF55LDzE&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuBtTYUuc5Pyo4V7xZ2HNtf4)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.